# Is it possible to re-group the result of using a LINQ GroupBy()?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-3.0, group-by

If I have used LINQ's GroupBy() method to create a grouped enumeration, is it possible to regroup that result under another key system? That is, if I grouped all of the objects by property X for one part of the code, is it possible to subsequently group that collection by property Y of property X at a later point in the code?

Comment: I suggest you break down your question into smaller questions, or try to state concisely what you're trying to achieve.... Give a SO user some example input and desired output and you'll get a solution within seconds. Write a wall of text and all you get is "tl;dr" :-)

Comment: @dtb The question is right at the top - if I've created an IEnumerable<IGrouping<X,T>>, can I convert this into an IEnumerable<IGrouping<Y,T>> directly? That's why I put the horizontal break, really. I added the "wall of text" so that if anyone is confused by the short, complete question at the top, they can read the text to get a clearer picture.

Comment: Of course, given that you could answer the question without said wall of text, no reason to keep it, aye?

Comment: I've got the feeling that there might be a more elegant, better performance solution to your actual problem. Re-grouping smells to me somewhat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I didn't read your question, but this works:

```
var groupedByProperty1 = myEnumerable.GroupBy(x => x.Property1);

var groupedByProperty2 = groupedByProperty1.SelectMany(g => g)
                                           .GroupBy(x => x.Property2);
```

Is that what you're looking for by any chance?

Comment: As it turns out, this is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

This slightly more complex way may be useful in some circumstances:

- The key 'columns' are not present in the data items themselves
- You want to base the new key directly on the existing grouped by key.

I found I needed to regroup based on an additional criteria that was too complex for a Linq-SQL expression and this is the approach I came up with for that situation.

Basically what I'm doing is :

- Flatten the list of items into a new list of key value pairs containing the existing key + data item
- Regrouping based upon your new key - which is directly based on the existing key

Note: I created an object `DateTime_PaymentStatus` to represent the key. If you do this be sure to add an `Equals()` method to the class or you'll get no actual grouping!

```
 // sample to regroup based on modifying an existing key
 var regrouped = grouped. 

                        SelectMany(x => // each x is an individual grouping (Key + List) 

                            // flatten the list, retaining the key each item was grouped by
                            x.Select(y => new 
                            { 
                                Key = x.Key, 
                                Item = y
                            })).

    // regroup based upon the existing key
    GroupBy(x => new DateTime_PaymentStatus 
            { 
                // group based on date + payment status
                Date = x.Key.Date, 
                PaymentStatus = PaidOrUnpaid(x.Key.PaymentStatus)   // call function here that is not SQL compatible
            });
```